# ¿Cómo hago para sumar "int" y "str"? o Para transformar la variable

Tags: python, python-3.x

A partir de `total_lista` es que el codigo empieza a dar problema, no sé como hacer que se realice esa operación. El Pycharm me señala esto:

```
line 16, in <module>
    total_lista += numero
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'str'
```

Tengo que crear un programa que calcule la media de los elementos de la lista de números introducida por el usuario.

Muchas gracias de antemano!

```
numeros_del_usuario = []
numero_del_usuario = ""

while not numero_del_usuario == "Finalizar":
    numero_del_usuario = input("Dime un numero: ")
    if numero_del_usuario.isdigit():
            numeros_del_usuario.append(numero_del_usuario)
            print("Número añadido")

cantidad_lista = len(numeros_del_usuario)
total_lista = 0
total_neto = 0

for numero in numeros_del_usuario:
    total_lista += numero
    total_neto = total_lista / cantidad_lista

print("La media de todos los numeros de la lista es {}".format(total_neto))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El input toma lo que le ingreses como si fuera una cadena de texto, por eso te lanza el error de intentar concatenar string a int,
como tu solo ingresaste valores numericos, al momento de poner:

```
for numero in numeros_del_usuario:
    total_lista += numero
    total_neto = total_lista / cantidad_lista
```

Basta con poner lo siguiente:

```
for numero in numeros_del_usuario:
    total_lista += int(numero)
    total_neto = total_lista / cantidad_lista
```

Al encerrar un string pero que es un entero, en la funcion int() lo convierte a entero.